# Highlight a property/variable when its value gets changed during debugging

Tags: visual-studio-2008, debugging

Is it possible when debugging to set a watch on a property or variable, and then have the debugger highlight the line where the value is changed.

I've had a situation where I spent ages going through the code trying to find in which line of code the variable had its value updated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++, use [Data Breakpoints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/350dyxd0.aspx). In C#/VB.NET, this option is not possible. The best you can do is put a breakpoint on the property's setter, and if it a field or an auto property, turn it into a regular property with backing field, and then put a breakpoint on it.

Resharper has a wonderful feature called "Value Tracking" (accessible through Ctrl+Alt+Shift+A) which automates the process of finding where a variable had its value updated, and does so in a second, so if there aren't too many such places, you could just quickly flip through them (with Ctrl+Alt+Pageup/Pagedown) and set a breakpoint in each.

Comment: That's great, I'll have to check Resharper out.